# xcode-select: Failed to locate 'clang'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode14, xcode-command-line-tools

When I try to run the clang command, I get the following error:

```
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'clang', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

And then I'm getting this error:

> The "clang" command requires the command line developer tools. Would
> you like to install the tools now?

If I click "Install", I continue getting the same error.

I have tried: `xcode-select --install`

But that gives the following error:

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use
> "Software Update" to install updates

My computer is an Apple M1, Monterey 12.5.

How can I install clang?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure Xcode packages are up-to-date. Try running `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`.

Also, you can try opening Xcode after the update and accepting the prompt to load essential development tools.